# WSO2 classpath -- what is it and where is it?

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-as

Using WSO2 AS 5.2.1 been unable to read a xml file in the classpath. Here is the code and the accompanying error:

```
try {
        InputStreamReader inputReader =new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(xmlFile.getName())); 
        HolidayInitializer holidayInit = new HolidayInitializer();
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputReader);
        institutionVumcHolidays = holidayInit.processHolidays(xmlStreamReader);
        log.info(getClass().getSimpleName() + " loadHolidays() Found Holidays config file in classpath");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(getClass().getSimpleName() + " loadHolidays() Holidays config file does not exist in classpath", e);
    }
```

And the output is:

```
2015-05-26 02:49:14 ERROR ExternalCallbackWebServiceImpl:343 - ExternalCallbackWebServiceImpl loadHolidays() Holidays config file does not exist in classpath

java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\wso2as-5.2.1\Holidays.xml (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
```

No matter where I stuff the xml file in WEB-INF/classes or in the directory of the source file, it keeps looking for that file in WSO2_HOME (installation directory). Very dire situation. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: This is exception is because you are trying to create a File object for a location which does not exist. Where did you initialize xmlFile?

Comment: The file has been provided under WEB-INF/classes. The absolute path of the file is c:\ws02-5.2.1\repository\deployment\server\webapps\mock\WEB-INF\classes. What I don't understand is why is WSO2 looking for the file under c:\wso2-5.2.1?

Comment: Alternately, when I copied the file over to c:\wso2as-5.2.1\Holidays.xml, the application ran as expected. I need help in figuring out how to read a classpath resource using WS02. Thanks.

Comment: can you try with getClass().getResourceAsStream()

Comment: Hi Thusitha: still getting this error- java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\WSO2AS~1.1\Holidays.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Reported as a bug https://wso2.org/jira/browse/WSAS-1953?filter=-2

Answer (score 0):

You can read the config file with the following,

context.getServletContext().getResource("/META-INF/holidays.xml")

thanks.